# UIAutomator - How to click the menu item

Tags: android, menuitem, android-uiautomator

I have automated go to setting in android phone using UI Automator and i clicked the menu using "getUiDevice().pressMenu();" and its opened menu with 3 sub menu item and i want to click the second menu by using name or index or id , please help how to click the sub menu in Android UIAutomator ?

Comment: Any one please help me to click the sub menu using UIAutomator ?

Answer (score 0):

This overflow menu icon `ImageView` with the three dots has no id ...

but one can get it by it's description:

```
UiObject2 menuButton = this.mDevice.findObject(By.desc("More options"));

/* open the menu */
if(menuButton != null && menuButton.isClickable()) {
    menuButton.click();
    menuButton.recycle();
} else {
    Assert.fail();
}
```

Then one can click menu items by their index:

```
ArrayList<UiObject2> menu = (ArrayList<UiObject2>) this.mDevice.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.ListView")).getChildren();

/* click the menu item at index 0 */
UiObject2 menu_action = menu.get(0);
if (menu_action != null && menu_action.isClickable()) {
    menu_action.click();
    menu_action.recycle();
} else {
    Assert.fail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use clazz method is working

```
 UiObject2 item = mDevice.findObject(By.clazz("android.widget.ListView"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'uiautomatorviewer' tool and view the text/description/resource id/index of your menu items displayed there.

To use uiautomatorviewer tool :

```
[1] Connect your device.
[2] Open command prompt and type 'uiautomatorviewer'.
[3] Open the particular screen of whose elements you want to view (in this case - your  menu items).
[4] Press the green 'Device Screenshot' button  next to file open in top left.
```

Hover on the screenshot to view the text/description/resource id/index of the elements of the screen and you can use whatever is being displayed there.

Comment: Thanks Smriti for your update . this info i know already. I want to automate clicking menu item in UIAutomator , I want to know what is the exact code which will click second menu item using UIAutomator? Please help me for this !

Comment: You can use the text(i guess that would be visible) which you will be seeing in uiautomatorviewer and then use it as -                          new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("give text here")).click(); or if this doesn't work , you can also go for (x,y) coordinates position of the menu item as use it as - getUiDevice.click(x,y);